# Ubuntu stuck in Grub Menu Loop. Unable to boot any version

Tags: 18.04, grub2, 19.10

I was using Ubuntu 19.10 and yesterday there was an update. After updating I turned off the pc and when I turned it on again today, it was stuck in loop at grub menu. Not even the screen with Ubuntu logo and 5 dots appears. I tried all the kernels available, set nomodeset but the problem didn't solve. Then I tried to reinstall 19.10 from usb but it was still stuck in the loop. Then I tried 18.04.4 but the problem still persists. Now, I can't even factory reset, as I've cleared all the partitions when reinstalling 19.10. So, please help me

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue yesterday and figured out that
`grub` `2.04-1ubuntu12` -> `2.04-1ubuntu12.2` upgrade leaving you with an unbootable system
(I found no reason why).

Here are a few steps that helped me:

1. Try to reinstall 19.10
2. Uncheck "Download updates while installing" during the installation
3. After installation you need to hold grub packages to prevent them
   from updating:
   `sudo apt-mark hold 'grub*'`
4. Finally you can execute `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am now waiting for 20.04 and for the mean time, using Mint, which has been so far great experience but even in Mint, after updating to kernel 5.3.0-42, it too stuck in boot menu loop but works fine with older kernel. I just hope Ubuntu works on this bigad this isn't first time my laptop got stuck in unbootable loop. So, I'll probably not try your solution but thanks anyway for your help